# If $(x_n)\to b$ and $x_n\lt b$ for all $n$, is $(x_n)$ eventually monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to assume otherwise and derive a contradiction, but since $x_n - x_{n+1}$ is an arbitrary small distance, I don't see that convergence can get the job done, nor whether my conjecture is true. I am guessing not, but the truth of this statement would help me with another proof which I already checked as answered. Now I am not satisfied with my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
$$
x_{2n} = b - \frac 1n\\
x_{2n+1} = b- 2^{-n}
$$
for a counterexample.

Comment: I had a sinking feeling that a counterexample could be constructed. I played around with points on paper and thought there could be one. Perhaps you can look art my question about left handed limits and give me some advice there. I don't see how to do tot without a monotonic sequence. In any case, thanks. I will check this question as answered as soon as the time limit is up.

Comment: Can you give a link to that question?

Comment: @MPW http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716380/prove-that-if-f-is-bounded-and-nondecreasing-on-a-b-then-lim-fx-as-x

Comment: the first answer is perfect imo/

Comment: Beyond hints, what am I missing there, if you don't mind helping me? I can see that the function will converge for the subsequence, but how does that establish the limit?

Comment: you show that every converging subsequence converge to the same limit. When you consider a given converging subsequence, consider a monotonic sub-subsequence. The limit is always the same (this is the limit of the monotonic sequences).