# Which definition of right/left limit is correct?

Tags: real-analysis

In Elementary Real Analysis by Bruckner, Bruckner, and Thomson, it is stated on page 187 that right hand limit exists if every decreasing sequence satisfies $f(e_n)/to L, with the other criteria being the usual definition of there limit in ethers of sequences. This is important to me because it determines whether I can or cannot currently prove that a bounded monotonic sequence has a limit, as explored in this post: [Prove that if $f$ is bounded and nondecreasing on $(a,b)$ then lim $f(x) $as $x$ approaches $b$ from the left exists.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716380/prove-that-if-f-is-bounded-and-nondecreasing-on-a-b-then-lim-fx-as-x). In my analysis book by Sherbert and Bartle, it is stated on page 112 that all sequences not just monotonic sequences must work. Is the definition standardized? Any help is much appreciated. I have been wrestling with this proof for awhile now.

Comment: After getting some help on a related question, I suspect the first book watered down the requirement for beginners.

Comment: The way you can define one sided limits in terms of sequences usually relies on the how they are defined in terms of $\epsilon - \delta$. For example the left limit is defined just as the usual limit except that, if $x \to x_0^-$ then $x$ is in the nbhd to the left of $x_0$ only. I.e $x\in (x_0-\delta, x_0)$

Comment: Can you give a link in Google books to Bartle's book in which he says any sequence will work? I don't think a decreasing sequence will give you the left limit, if we're considering any sequence.

Comment: I was probably too brief. Bartle did include the necessity that $x_n\gt x$ where $x$ is the limit for all $n$. I am still trying to find the right balance on this site between giving too little versus too much information. Anyway, thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two definitions are right-hand limits: let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $ \lim_{x \downarrow a} f(x) = L \quad \textrm{if}$

$$\forall (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset (a,\infty) \quad \textrm{such that} \quad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = a \quad \textrm{we have} \quad  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = L. \quad (1)$$

$$ \forall (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset (a,\infty) \quad \textrm{such that} \quad   x_n \downarrow a \quad \textrm{as} \quad n \rightarrow \infty \quad \textrm{we have} \quad  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = L.  \quad(2)$$

You seem to be worried that these definitions are 'different'. In fact, they are equivalent. Clearly $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$. So let us show $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$:

Take an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset (a,\infty) \quad \textrm{such that} \quad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = a$. Assuming (2) we must show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = L.$ To do so we assume the following:

**Lemma** Suppose $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb{R}$ has the following property: $\exists L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that from any subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ we can extract a subsequence $(x_{n_{k_r}})_{r=1}^{\infty}$ with limit $L$ as $r \to \infty$. Then in fact $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$.

See this page for proof of this Lemma: [Sufficient condition for convergence of a real sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173590/sufficient-condition-for-convergence-of-a-real-sequence)

Now take an arbitrary subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$. You should be able to show (by induction) that we may extract a subsequence $(x_{n_{k_r}})$ of $(x_{n_k})$ which approaches $a$ monotonically from above as $r \to \infty$. But now by (2) we have $$\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_{k_r}}) = L.$$

We have verified the hypothesis of the Lemma for the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and the required convergence follows.

Comment: Thanks. I see the equivalence now. Analysis is great, but it's going to take me some time to internalize, clearly.

Comment: No problem! Yes, it takes a while.